# How to query for objects which has certain parse objects contained in a relation

Tags: parse-platform, message

I have a messaging system in Parse, a `Message` class and a `User` class. Each `Message` has a relation called `senders` to multiple users.

How do I query for all messages for a single user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query should give the expected result:

```
var query = new Parse.Query('Message');
query.equalTo('senders', user);
```

Comment: I don't understand. The ```senders``` field should be a relation, and the docs for ```PFQuery``` doesn't specify this behavior...

Comment: I use this request in cloud code, I don't know how PFQuery works.